# How to export dataframes from dictionary to Excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dictionary containing dataframes. I have to export them to excel to one file with sheets having one dataframe in each sheet with its name. How can I do this? Manually would be like this:

```
dict_of_regions = dict(iter(data.groupby('blok')))
marketing = dict_of_regions['marketing']
hr = dict_of_regions['hr ']

with pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\to_excel.xlsx') as writer:  
   marketing.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='marketing')
   hr.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='hr')
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop over your `dict_of_regions`:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\to_excel.xlsx') as writer:
    for sheet_name, df in dict_of_regions.items():
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name)
```